# child theme of non responsive one

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a non responsive theme with a mobile version of it inside (contains style.css, functions, index etc.)> I have created a child theme that works good for the web version>> when I included the style.ss of the mobile version the web version have faults (the site can not distinguish between the two styles and things overlap, I guess)>>
I need to make the mobile version work from the child theme... I've enqueued it this way

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'mobile-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mobile/style.css' );
```

hope someone can help

Comment: hi first check the /mobile/style.css load correctly in view source and check path ? and for child theme you should use the code like this wp_enqueue_style( 'mobile-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mobile/style.css' ); this will load the css

Comment: first, thanks, using the code i put above the css loads, but causes errors (misplacement of elements)>>>> the original theme automatically redirects to what is suitable according the the device>>> in ht child I do not now???

Comment: i can't get you can you confirm the your code when you check the link in view source shows correct or not?

Comment: I mean that the child theme works fine for web. but after I included the mobile V things missed up. I believe it not the right way to do it for moble

Comment: ok for the desktop you have style.css and for mobile, you have mobile/style.css . let rename mobile/style.css to responsive.css and try will that make change?

Comment: It reloads the responsive file but the site missed up for mobile , https://imgur.com/cRm1iDq   >>> still takes somethimgs fron the main style >>> as not knowing it is for mobile

Comment: hmm it looks like you do not add media query or something to add css if you add the same class in both CSS without distinguished for deskop or mobile version it will overload the css.

Comment: this is all the functions.php in the mobile https://imgur.com/4W0JEr7

Comment: ok so for mobile you change the template check this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile can help

Comment: ya. now css of the mobile loads only for mobiles , bur still has errors...  does the vesion has any thing to do with that ???

Comment: no what error it is showing

Comment: no error shown, the style missed and overlap from the two file. fortunately, wp_is_mobile() you suggested worked just fine, and now I converted the site rtl by putting the file in the child theme, and made another one for the mobile in child/mobile/rtl.css and enqueued them the the if statement the web worked fine for rtl but the mobile not because it loads both rtls in this case and the style goes yauk.

Comment: can u send screenshot of code

Comment: thank you, was solved. appreciate the effort